# How to set Pycharm with Ansible plugin to do code completion for variables?

Tags: ansible, pycharm, yaml, code-completion

I'm using **Pycharm** free community version `2016.2.3` with `YAML/Ansible` plugin, but I don't manage to trigger the code completion for variables. (I do know for sure it's possible.) Is there some configuration I need to set prior to that?

Comment: Plugin link: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7792

Comment: Any one have a clue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope you solved your problem already, but for the reference, as I had the same problem and Google led me to this question, here is how I solved it:

PyCharm comes with another YAML Plugin which will take all your Ansible YAML files under its control. Have a look if the favicon of your your files in the filesystem browser and the editor tabs have the Ansible logo.

Those editor tabs, associated with the Ansible/YAML plugin, are able to trigger code completion for variables. Those without the logo, do not.

For me the solution was to disable the other YAML Plugin.

Answer (score 4):

YAML/Ansible plugin registers its own file type `YAML/Ansible` in IntelliJ IDEA based IDEs (PhpStorm, WebStorm, PyCharm,  CLion, RubyMine, Rider, GoLand, DataGrip, etc).

As an alternative to disabling original YAML plugin, use can reassign file types.

Go to `File` => `Settings`, then `Editor` => `File Types`. Click in the `YAML` type and remove `*.yaml` and `*.yml` patterns. Then click on the `YAML/Ansible` file type and add those patterns there.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this plugin.

The recently released [Ansible](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14893-ansible) plugin helps you write and work with ansible files. it's totally compatible with built-in YAML plugin. Although it has many good features but it still can't suggest variable names but i'm actively developing it and it will do that soon.